# Managed message broker with fanout load balancing exactly once per message to each consumer group

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I’m trying to find a managed fan-out message broker that works in (what I think is) a pretty standard use-case, but I can’t find anything that meets my needs. These are my criteria, in order of importance:

1) Clients, both producers and consumers, are Python 3.7+.

2) Messages may be arbitrarily large. In practice they aren’t massive but might be larger than SQS’s 256KB limit. Putting messages into S3 and sending a reference to them isn’t practical, even if managed transparently via a client library.

3) My producer needs to be able to send messages (of a particular type) to a single destination (for that message type) and be completely isolated from what, if any, consumers are subscribed to that destination.

4) My consumers should be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to/from the destination without my needing to reconfigure anything in the producer(s). (Which is pretty much implied by #3 but AWS didn’t seem to think so.)

5) A given consumer application may need to be implemented using any number of parallel processes for performance reasons (Python typically needing multiprocessing over multithreading), and potentially from different nodes. I want to treat all of the parallel processes of a given consumer as a single logical subscription unit and load balance each message to one and only one consumer process of that subscription unit.

6) If a consumer explicitly nacks a message, or no ack is received in an expected timeframe, the message is redelivered promptly to all the consumer group(s) that have not acked it and not to any that have.

7) The broker service should be managed, i.e. an AWS service that I can treat as a black box.

8) Ideally the destination would be a topic with some sort of wildcard mechanism that can be used to form a hierarchy of message types (e.g. booking-* matching booking-xyz and booking-abc etc).

Notes:

1)  I’ve tried SNS+SQS but it doesn’t support messages over 256KB properly

2)  I’ve tried Amazon MQ but it doesn’t support #3 (they said send to multiple queues and/or use selectors but this necessitates changing and restarting the producer each time I add or remove a consumer and completely breaks isolation of concerns). #5 doesn’t seem to work either.

3)  I’d like to use Kinesis but it doesn’t seem to support fanout at all.

4)  I like RabbitMQ lots but it’s not managed.

Comment: Did you looked up cloudamqp... ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the desired behaviour is available in both:

1) ActiveMQ using Virtual Topics (with a bit of reconfiguration in AmazonMQ) http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html

2) Google Pub/Sub out of the box https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview

Who knew? (apparently not AWS.)